# Regular Expression. remove dashes.

Tags: c#, regex

I have a large array of names.  The software names them really long and doesn't have a way to override it.  I want to just get out the file name I need. I've been using regex because it feels like it should be able to get just this part of the string. Any help would be great I've spent a day with no luck.

Here is the output.

UCM - S - Loading 1H_lester.virata.sfw811 - Sheet - 1H-S11-00 - LEVEL 01 FOUNDATION PLAN

UCM - S - Loading 1H_lester.virata.sfw811 - Sheet - 1H-S11-00A - LEVEL 01 REINFORCEMENT PLAN

UCM - S - Loading 1H_lester.virata.sfw811 - Sheet - 1H-S11-01A - LEVEL 02 ROOF REINFORCEMENT PLAN

I want to return: 
1HS1100
1HS1100A
1HS1101A

Comment: Where's the regex you've tried? ... It looks like you need to include that.

Comment: "\d\w\W\w\d\d\W\d\d\w?" I used this and then replaced the "-" woth "".  I'd like it to just be taken care of by regex.  but can't find a way.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the hyphenated strings with `\w+-[\w-]+` ([example](https://regex101.com/r/ZjVQ1r/1)), and then process them with a substitution / replace command to substitute `'-'` with `''`.

Comment: this is how I'm doing it at the moment, but you're regex is more elegant so I will replace mine with yours.

Answer (score 0):

**"^[^\d]+(\d\w)_\w+.\w+.(\w+)[^\d]+(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)[^\d]+(\d+)"**

Just combine all the matches from the above regular expression and that should do it.